# what are different types of cache from an interview point of view? Is cache always in-memory

Tags: caching, cdn, distributed, in-memory

I know there are different types of cache like:

1. in-memory
2. disk cache
3. distributed
4. application server cache
5. Global cache
6. CDN

However, I am not sure whether any of the above types is actually a subtype of the other in the list. The list seems to be ever-growing. Can someone clearly list down the major cache types, their subtypes and examples

Also can someone confirm if cache is always in-memory?

I am actually preparing for interview and types of cache and the scenarios where they are used is important.

Any article/youtube video that clearly explains the concept would be helpful too.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ️ What are you interviewing for? Caches matter when the resources you're using are constrained. If it's for a large networking application, you're going to find different caches relevant than if you're developing for a small memory constrained application on bare metal.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I am preparing for application developer(Software Engineer) interview. So wanted to know the ctaegories of caches, their types, scenarios where they fit in and their examples.

Comment: Cache is one of those terms that can have a general definition, many application-specific specializations, and it's going to vary from field to field, and book to book. Grab whatever textbook you have that explains caches, and go with that. When they ask you "describe caches", just explain you're using the definition out of that book. If you have experience using caches in any of your applications, that's a good time to talk about your experience, which is more important than the book definition imo.

Comment: "Software Engineer" covers a LOT of domains. When you say application developer do you mean a smartphone app? Desktop app? Nuclear power plant control app? What product does the company make that you'll be working on? It's not software (unless it is).

Comment: I'll be working on an online travel website something like booking.com